# Axios Delete not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

In my CRUD webapp based on Laravel 5.6 and Vue.js 2 Add, Edit and Show are working fine. But Delete is not working because axios.delete is not sending id to controller. Console.log in Home.vue is showing correct id and key values. Following is the code and result what I am getting in controller. Please tell my mistake. Also do I really need a Route for delete in web.php?

### Controller

```
public function destroy(Sms $sms)
    {
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w", true) or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "Print_r: ". print_r($sms) ."\r\nID: ". $sms->id;
        //fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($sms, TRUE));
        //die();
        Sms::where('id',$sms->id)->delete();
```

### }

### Home.vue

```
del(key,id){
            if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
                this.loading = !this.loading
                /*axios.delete(`/sms/${id}`)*/
                axios.delete(`sms/${id}`, {params: {id: `${id}`}})
                .then((response)=> {this.lists.splice(key,1);this.loading = !this.loading})
                .catch((error)=> this.errors = error.response.data.errors)
                console.log(`KEY:${key} ID:${id}`);
            }
```

### }

### web.php

### Route::delete('sms/{id}', 'smsController@destroy');

### newfile.txt

App\Sms Object
(
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => created_at
            [1] => updated_at
        )

```
[connection:protected] => 
[table:protected] => 
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[keyType:protected] => int
[incrementing] => 1
[with:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[withCount:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[perPage:protected] => 15
[exists] => 
[wasRecentlyCreated] => 
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[original:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[changes:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[casts:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dates:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dateFormat:protected] => 
[appends:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[observables:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[relations:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[touches:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[timestamps] => 1
[visible:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[fillable:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[guarded:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )
```

)

Comment: And it's not a case of case sensitivity for the class name, right?

Comment: No, it's not a case of case sensitivity.

Answer (score 3):

try to change `axios.delete` to `axios.post`, and add a `_method` field with the value `delete` in the data to be sent. like so

```
axios.post(`sms/${id}`, {params: {id: `${id}`}, _method: 'delete'})
```

Comment: Sorry dear, not working. I have tried following:

axios.delete(`/sms/${id}`)
axios.delete(`/sms/${id}`, {params: {'id': id}})
axios.post(`sms/${id}`, {params: {id: `${id}`}, _method: 'delete'})